# How to load JSON data associated with each link onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have created a dynamic link based on JSON data, The problem I am having, when I click on the links is its not loading the information associated for each of the link.

for example when i click on Algebra it should load the id and author  info. But currently it work for only the last link.

How can I make it work for every link so that it loads for each one?

here is my code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>



var url= 'sample.json';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'jsoncback',
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
        //$('.bookname').empty();
        var html ='';
         $.each(data.class, function(key, value) {
            console.log(value.name+  " value name");
            console.log(value.desc +  " val desc");
           $('.bookname').empty();
            html+= '<div class="books" id="authorInfo-'+key+'">';
            html+=  '<a href="#" >'+value.name+ key+'</a>';
            html+=  '</div>';   

           $(".bookname").append(html);
            var astuff = "#authorInfo-"+key+" a";
            console.log(value.desc +  " val desc");
            $(astuff).click(function() {
             var text = $(this).text();
             console.log(text+  " text");
                var bookdetails =''
                 $("#contentbox").empty();                          
                    $.each(value.desc, function(k,v) {
                       console.log(v.id +"-");
                       console.log(v.author +"<br>");
                        bookdetails+= v.id +' <br> ' 
                        bookdetails+= v.author + '<br>';

                    }); 
                  $("#contentbox").append(bookdetails);         
            });
          });

    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log("error " +e.message);
    }
});



        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        <div class="bookname">

        </div>
        <div id="contentbox">

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are updating the inner html of the element `bookname` in the loop, which will result the previously added handlers being removed from the child elements.

The calls `$('.bookname').empty();` and `$(".bookname").append(html);` within the loop is the culprits here. You can rewrite the procedure as something like this

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var url = 'sample.json';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'jsoncback',
        success: function (data) {
            var $bookname = $('.bookname').empty();
            $.each(data.class, function (key, value) {
                var html = '<div class="books author-info" id="authorInfo-' + key + '">';
                html += '<a href="#" class="title">' + value.name + key + '</a>';
                html += '</div>';
                $(html).appendTo($bookname).data('book', value);
            });
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("error " + e.message);
        }
    });

    var $contentbox = $("#contentbox");
    $('.bookname').on('click', '.author-info .title', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var value = $(this).closest('.books').data('book');

        var text = $(this).text();
        console.log(text + " text");
        var bookdetails = '';
        $.each(value.desc, function (k, v) {
            console.log(v.id + "-");
            console.log(v.author + "<br>");
            bookdetails += v.id + ' <br> ';
            bookdetails += v.author + '<br>';

        });
        $contentbox.html(bookdetails);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to run your code but I am getting syntax error on " var html += '<div class="books author-info" id="authorInfo-' + key + '">';" Is there something i missed?

Comment: @user244394 let me see

Comment: @user244394 why do you wan't an alternate... what is wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$(astuff).click(function()
```

to

```
$(document).on("click", "#astuff", function()
```

I assume "astuff" is a ID and you forgot the number sign and quotes in your original selector.  The jQuery "click" listener only listens for events on elements that were rendered during the initial page load.  You want to use the "on" listener, it'll look for events on elements currently in the DOM.